# React router v6: catch all "*" path does not work when using nested routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the following two files

**AppRoutes.tsx**

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import NotFound from "../pages/NotFound";
import MessageRoutes from "../features/messages/routes/MessageRoutes";
import Home from "../pages/Home";

export default function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/messages/*" element={<MessageRoutes />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

**MessageRoutes.tsx**

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoutes from "../../../routes/ProtectedRoutes";
import MessageOverview from "../pages/MessageOverview";
import NewMessage from "../pages/NewMessage";

export default function MessageRoutes() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<MessageOverview />} />
        <Route path="/new" element={<NewMessage />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Because I'm using the path "/messages/*" to capture all paths that start with /messages, my MessageRoutes component takes care of these nested routes. I have a final "*" route in the AppRoutes component to capture any url that the app does not support. But if the path would be "/messages/loremipsum", react router does not catch the NotFound route because everything that starts with "/messages" will be handled with the MessageRoutes component.

Does this mean that in every nested route component I now have to add a final `<Route path="\*" element={\<NotFound /\>} /\>` again, just to support a final catch all route? I don't like this approach. Is there no absolute final catch all for every route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that in every nested route component I now have to add
> a final `<Route path="\*" element={<NotFound />} \>` again

Yes, absolutely. Each `Routes` component manages its own "scope" of routes for what it can match. For example if the current URL path is `"/messages/loremipsum"` the root `Routes` component matches the `"/messages/*"` and correctly renders the `MessageRoutes` component. The `MessageRoutes` component's `Routes` component then works on matching on the next path segment. Since there is no `"*/loremipsum"` route path you need another "catch-all" route to handle this.

The issue is that a `Routes` component isn't aware of what ***descendent*** routes any of its routes *may* possibly be rendering.

Example:

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import NotFound from "../pages/NotFound";
import MessageRoutes from "../features/messages/routes/MessageRoutes";
import Home from "../pages/Home";

export default function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/messages/*" element={<MessageRoutes />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoutes from "../../../routes/ProtectedRoutes";
import MessageOverview from "../pages/MessageOverview";
import NewMessage from "../pages/NewMessage";
import NotFound from "../pages/NotFound";

export default function MessageRoutes() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<MessageOverview />} />
        <Route path="/new" element={<NewMessage />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

If you want to have a single "catch-all" route then you'll need to have a single routes configuration.

Example:

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import MessageOverview from "../pages/MessageOverview";
import NewMessage from "../pages/NewMessage";
import NotFound from "../pages/NotFound";
import Home from "../pages/Home";

export default function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
        <Route path="/messages">
          <Route index element={<MessageOverview />} />
          <Route path="new" element={<NewMessage />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Now when/if the URL path is `"/messages/loremipsum"` then *this* `Routes` component knows what ***nested*** routes it is rendering and can match and can correctly render `NotFound`.